# Relativpronomen im Genitiv, wenn ein Adjektiv dabeisteht

Tags: relative-pronoun

Ich habe eine Frage über Relativpronomen im Genitiv. Wie kann ich diesen Satz verstehen?

> Bald gibt es den Laptop von ________ besonder___ Eigenschaft___ ich schon viel gehört habe.
>
> Antwort:
>   Bald gibt es den Laptop von **dessen** besonder**en** Eigenschaft**en** ich schon viel gehört habe.

Warum Eigenschaft**en**? Ich dachte Eigenschaft (Singular) ist richtig. Aber es war falsch. Kann jemand darüber erklären, bitte?

Comment: Aber eigentlich scheint dir das Relativpronomen klar zu sein. Denn darüber stellst du keine Frage. Du fragst nur nach Singular/Plural des Subjekts des Relativsatzes, das hängt aber nicht mit dem Pronomen zusammen.

Comment: Du musst den Relativsatz mit Kommas abtrennen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beide Möglichkeiten sind richtig:

> 1. Bald gibt es den Laptop, von dessen **besonderen Eigenschaften** ich schon viel gehört habe.
> 2. Bald gibt es den Laptop, von dessen **besonderer Eigenschaft** ich schon viel gehört habe.

Es könnte sei, dass in der Werbung nur eine einzige Eigenschaft hervorgehoben wird, z.B. dass dieser spezielle Laptop 24 Stunden lang betrieben werden kann, ohne dass der Akku dabei leer wird. Wenn der Laptop sonst keine Besonderheiten hat, würde die Variante 2 korrekt sein.

Meist ist es aber so, dass in der Werbung mit mehreren besonderen Eigenschaften geworben wird (ultrahohe Auflösung, superschnelle CPU, riesiger RAM-Speicher, 2 TB Festplatte, usw.). In diesem Fall hat das Gerät mehrere besondere Eigenschaften, und dann ist Variante 1 die bessere Wahl.

Aber rein aus der Grammatik heraus sind beide Möglichkeiten korrekt.

Comment: Danke für die klare Antwort!

Answer (score 2):

Was man hier verwenden muss, hängt von der beabsichtigten Bedeutung ab. Wenn es sich um eine einzelne besondere Eigenschaft handelt, muss man Singular verwenden, wenn es um mehrere Eigenschaften geht, Plural. Das hat aber mit dem Relativsatz nichts zu tun, und ist nicht anders, als bei anderen Verwendungen des Singular oder Plural.

Die beiden Sätze für die jeweiligen Bedeutungen sehen syntaktisch dann wie folgt aus:

> Bald gibt es den Laptop, von dessen besonderer Eigenschaft ich schon viel gehört habe.
>
> Bald gibt es den Laptop, von dessen besonderen Eigenschaften ich schon viel gehört habe.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Ich habe alles verstanden!

Answer (score 0):

Ich füge eine Anmerkung über das Adjektiv hinzu, die aus dem Duden Band 4, Auflage 9, kommt.

2.6.2.3 Die Genetivformen dessen, deren und derer

Seite 282->
[...]
Im Gegensatz zu den possessiven Artikelwörtern behalten *dessen* und *deren* ihren Kasus, kongruieren also nicht mit dem folgenden Substantiv. Sie bewirken auch **nicht**, dass ein folgendes attributives Adjektiv schwach flektiert würde - hier sind **nur starke Formen** korrekt (1526).[...]

Beispiel:

> "Das Bürogebäude, in dessen oberst**em** Stockwerk sich auch zwei
> Wohnungen befinden".

Comment: Was folgt daraus für die Frage?